# VS C++ add reference - No items found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm use VS 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. I want to add reference to lib to my project.

What I do:

1. Right click on "Reference" in solution explorer.
2. Add reference...
3. Windows shows and tell that: "No items found".

Already try to set "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" but still "No items found" statement occur.

Comment: You could try a .def file in the "Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Module Definition File" that contains the info for your Library.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a .def file in the "Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Module Definition File" that contains the info for your Library. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx

Or  Stack Overflow:

[C++ linker options for DLL (DEF, LIB, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755327/c-linker-options-for-dll-def-lib-etc)

has good instructions on how to add a library to your project and set the Linker's "Additional Dependencies".

PS... I've found it's difficult to take a non CLR project and try to convert it into a CLR project.  There are lots of switches to get it all right.  I've found it easier (when absolutely needed) to create a new CLR project and then copy the code over.  A clean CLR project will allow you to get to the "Add Reference" you are used to.  (Just be aware CLR adds a bit more memory processing behind the scenes and can lead to slightly slower code.)